# Run through terminal PYTHON

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Is there a way on a mac to make it so when you click on a python script it runs python filename.py through terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible with multiple methods. The easiest is simply right-clicking the script, opening the `Get Info` window and changing `Open With` to `Python Launcher (x.x.x)`.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Python Documentation: [4.1.1. How to run a Python script](http://docs.python.org/using/mac.html#how-to-run-a-python-script), you can set "Python Launcher" to your default program which uses pythonw. This assumes you have Leopard or later.

Comment: But that opens a bunch of other windows